# append a child to a div using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have div.I intend to loop through an array and create html element and hold it in an array & once iteration is complete I want to append this to  div. Here is what I did:

```
var bodyContent;
var a = document.getElementById("content");
console.log(content);
for(var i = 0,l = content.length; i<l;i++) {
    bodyContent+="<li><span>"+content[i]["checkBoxTemplate"]+"</span><span>"+content[i]["item"]+"</span></li>";
}
a.appendChild(bodyContent);
```

But it throwing this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
```

Have also tried with innerHTML

What exactly is wrong in it? I know it can be done using jQuery, but I strictly want to use javascript. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: What error do you get with `a.innerHTML`?

Comment: Appendchild requires a node (element object), you are passing a string. Use `a.innerHTML = bodyContent` Kind of what the error is saying to you.

Comment: What is within the `content` variable?

Comment: Or use [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.insertAdjacentHTML) instead of `appendChild`.

Comment: @Teemu has a nice alternative. This doesn't overwrite the content with other content as innerHTML does, but appends the string at the end of the node.

Comment: What's the error when you do `a.innerHTML = bodyContent;`? Btw, `bodyContent` will always start with `"undefined"` :)

Comment: Also, what's inside `content[i]["checkBoxTemplate"]`?

Comment: content is array of objects like var content =[ { "checkBoxTemplate":"Mango", "Price/Item":20 }, { "checkBoxTemplate":"Apple", "Price/Item":30 }] So I can iterate over this array of objects and create html –

Answer (score 3):

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

What is the difference:

`node.appendChild` needs a node. A node is an object. It represents HTML, XHTML, XML markup. They can be created programmatically with `document.createElement("node_name")` where *node_name* is the name of a node e.g. *div* or retrieved from the *DOM* with functions like `document.getElementById()`.

Example:

```
var a = document.getElementById("content");
var b = document.createElement("span"); //node
a.appendChild(b);
```

`node.innerHTML` gets or sets the content (with html markup). The value is always a *string*.

When the browser detects a change to a nodes content or its descendants it triggers a *re-flow*. Or redrawing of the node simply said. Any html markup in the node gets parsed. `innerHTML` as setter empties the current content and replaces it with the new content.

Example:

```
var a = document.getElementById("content");
var b = "<span>content</span>"; //string
a.innerHTML = b;
```

`node.insertAdjacentHTML()` is more advanced. It adds a string to the node's content or outside the element. It doesn't overwrite the content, but puts the new content inside or outside the node based upon the flag.

You can set four types of flags (from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.insertAdjacentHTML))

- `beforebegin` Before the element itself.
- `afterbegin` Just inside the element, before its first child.
- `beforeend` Just inside the element, after its last child.
- `afterend` After the element itself.

Example:

```
var a = document.getElementById("content");
var b = "<span>content</span>"; //string
a.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", b);
```

Comment: `'beforeend` would probably correspond `appendChild` better ; ).

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that your statement `content[i]["checkBoxTemplate"]` is going to do what you want it to do because `content[i]` is an element and you are combining it with strings so will end up with a string that looks like `[object someHTMLElement]`

In addition to `insertAdjacentHTML`, mentioned above you could use createElement or createElementNS to create each and every element and then use the setAttribute (or equivalent) to set the properties appropriately.

Your code would look something like this

```
var li = document.createElement('li');
var span = document.createElement('span');
li.appendChild(span);
var text = document.createTextNode('content of the span');
span.appendChild(text);
...
```

Comment: content is array of objects like
var content =[
 {
  "checkBoxTemplate":"Mango",
  "Price/Item":20
  
 },
 {
  "checkBoxTemplate":"Apple",
  "Price/Item":30
 }]
So I can iterate over this array of objects and create  html

Comment: Notice that there is no need anymore to use the cumbersone DOM text node creation. Instead, we can say `span.textContent = "content of the span"`.